# phonegap login page, how to keep user information

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a login page and i want to store user information. 
If user is null, send user to login page, else user will continue to use application.

```
$.mobile.changePage("index.html");
```

My code is:

```
var obj; //user information (json)
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#btnlogin").click(function(){
            var username=$("#lusername").val();
            var password=$("#lpassword").val();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Service1.asmx/Giris",
        data: "{'kullaniciadi':'"+ username+"' , 'sifre': '"+password+"'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {



             obj = jQuery.parseJSON( msg.d);
            if(obj!=null)
            {
                 $.mobile.changePage("index.html");
            }
            else alert("not found");

                                },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }



        });
    });
});
```

Because i'm using  `$.mobile.changePage("index.html");` i can use the same java script at every page, i use alert and i works

```
$('#illnessDetailsPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    alert(user);

});
```

My problem starts here, i use `var obj//user info` at the top of javascript but when page is change, it returns `null`.

Why it is null? (to learn javascript better) and how to solve problem?

Then how to control 'back' button to not load login page while logined?
I didnt find any example,
 Thank You in advance. 
(I dont want to use localStorage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you load a page, the resources are loaded again. This essentially means that the information you stored in javascript variable will be lost.

Now coming to your solution, since you are using phonegap and hence your app would be running on a webkit based browser. So I would suggest you to use localStorage.

Inside the login success function you can set the userInfo.

```
$("#btnlogin").click(function(){
        var username=$("#lusername").val();
        var password=$("#lpassword").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Service1.asmx/Giris",
    data: "{'kullaniciadi':'"+ username+"' , 'sifre': '"+password+"'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
             localStorage.setItem('userInfo', msg.d);
             //Your code here
    }
```

In other pages you can now just check this localstorage object. If it is null change the page to login page.

```
if(localStorage.getItem('userInfo') == null){
   $.mobile.changePage('login.html');
}
```

I would also advice you to check out indexedDb
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/IndexedDB