# Using JavaScript, I'm trying to store the url of each page the user clicks into an array so i can use that array for a back button

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, storage

Like the titles says, I'm trying to store the url of each page the user clicks on my site into an array so i can use that array for a back forward feature on my site. I'm trying it using JavaScript.

So in my header i have this code which checks if the desired array exists and creates it if it doesn't. I created it here so it would be global, rather than in the function where it would be local.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof myHistory == 'undefined') { // check if the array exists 
    var myHistory = new Array();
}
</script>
```

The function to add data to the array is at the very bottom of the page and is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function writetoArray () {
    var url = location.href; 
    myHistory.push(url); 
    alert("The pages in the array are:" + myHistory); 
}

</script>
```

I call the function with an onload event for the page.

The issue is, the array never gets past one item. myHistory[0] is correct but myHistory[1] is undefined.

Can anyone shed light on what i need to do for the array to store the urls I browse to to myHistory[1],[2], etc?

Thank you.

Comment: I think browsers already have back and forward button?

Comment: Thanks Duc Anh ... I've said that, beleive me, but the requester wants a back/forward on the breadcrumbs as well. If I can get the data to write to the dang array I think I'll be good. The first step is the hardest.

Comment: [They have an API for you to use back and forward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History). And for your question, unless you're using [local storage or alike](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage), JavaScript generally has the life time of that web page: once the page is navigated away, JavaScript "status" is discarded.

Comment: Thanks passerby .. i already use localstorage to pass the page id from each page to the feedback page to populate the feedback form. I'll try it here too but I hope I amn't limited to one varibale per session. All shall be revealed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you load a page, the resources are loaded again. This essentially means that the information you stored in javascript variable will be lost.

Now the solution to your problem is similar to the one i suggested here 
[How to keep user information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143763/phonegap-login-page-how-to-keep-user-information/19144078#19144078)

Specifically however the solution to your problem lies in [HTML 5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) , which however will work only for HTML 5 supported browsers.

Comment: Thanks Ghost. As luck would have it all browsers will be HTML5 supported. Thanks for that.